# MYSQL Query with 2 ORDER BYs on the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a Query that I want to return 2 ORDER BYs. When I run the Query itself, it keeps the priority on getting the ABS value. Is there anyway I can get around this so my query returns an organized list where Bananas is DESC from the smallest to the largest.

Query:

```
SELECT Apples, Bananas 
FROM TheJungle 
WHERE Strawberries = 1960 
ORDER BY ABS(9992-CAST(`Bananas` AS SIGNED)) LIMIT 13
```

I would like my query to return an organized list where Bananas is DESC from the smallest to the largest. Something like:

```
SELECT Apples, Bananas 
FROM TheJungle 
WHERE Strawberries = 1960 
ORDER BY ABS(9992-CAST(`Bananas` AS SIGNED)), Bananas DESC LIMIT 13
```

I cant post pictures of what my current query is returning since my rep isn't high enough.

Comment: Do not post pictures of texts. Put them into a `blockquote` block...

Comment: If you want to order by Bananas, why are you ordering by `ABS(...)` at all?

Comment: @Mat I want to get closest to the the value selected, the 9992 value in ABS()

Comment: what if you just  `ORDER BY ABS(9992-CAST(Bananas AS SIGNED)) DESC LIMIT 13` ?